# Ruby 2.4 Enumerable#sum breaks in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

In Rails 5.1.4 using Ruby 2.3.5, I get this behavior:

```
>> [].sum
#> nil
```

I'd like to upgrade to Ruby 2.4, where Enumerable#sum is implemented natively. Testing this in IRB using Ruby 2.4.2, I get this result:

```
>> [].sum
#> 0
```

That's OK, and I can handle the different result. But going back to the Rails console in Rails 5.1.4 using Ruby 2.4.2, I get this:

```
>> [].sum
#> NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

However, in a newly created Rails 5.1.4 project, I don't get this error. What's going on here?

Comment: Try `[].method(:sum).source_location` in the Rails console of your existing project to see if `sum` is being overridden somewhere. Also might be some clues in the stacktrace lines that come after `undefined method \`each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: There is no stack trace after the error. `[].method(:sum).source_location` returns `["/Users/mmo/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb", 148]`. It returns the same result in my newly created test project in which `[].sum` works properly.

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.4/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb) it definitely seems like something odd because you shouldn't have been getting the behaviour you described for Rails 5.1.4 using Ruby 2.3.5. (i.e. you should have been getting 0 not `nil` there too). In the source `Array#sum` will call `super` which is `Enumerable#sum` and [both implementations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb#L8) of that have a default of 0.

Comment: So it's looking like `[].sum` is calling `Array#sum` (the `source_location`) reported, but that is calling a customised `Enumerable#sum`. So you could try this: `[].method(:sum).super_method.source_location`

Comment: Was just typing another comment as you were replying :) - that included the suggestion to check `[].method(:sum).super_method.source_location`

Comment: In my newly created project, `[].method(:sum).super_method.source_location` returns `["/Users/mmo/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb", 31]`. In the existing project, it returns `["/Users/mmo/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/descriptive_statistics-2.5.1/lib/descriptive_statistics/sum.rb", 2]`. Looks like the descriptive_statistics gem is the source of the problem.

Comment: @mikej Thanks for the detective work. If you'd like to rephrase this conversation as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: Great! This could be useful for others coming across other slightly different problems too so I've written it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source for the Active Support enumerable extensions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.4/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb) it definitely seems like something odd is going on because you shouldn't have been getting the behaviour you described for Rails 5.1.4 using Ruby 2.3.5 i.e. you should have been getting 0 not `nil` there too.

Active Support's `Array#sum` checks if Ruby's own `sum` can be used by checking `first.is_a?(Numeric)`. This will be false for an empty array so the call to `super` will call `Enumerable#sum` and [both implementations of that](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb#L8) have a default of 0.

Try `[].method(:sum).source_location` in the Rails console of your existing project to see if `Array#sum` is being overridden somewhere.

if that returns the expected line from `active_support/c‌​ore_ext/enumerable.r‌​b` then the next step will be to check `[].method(:sum).super_method.source_location` and see if a customised `Enumerable#sum` is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your application have some overhidden on sum method. Look the example below with 2 new applications using the 2 different versions of ruby

```
/testapp# ruby --version
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux]
/testapp# rails --version
Rails 5.1.4
/testapp# rails c
irb(main):001:0> [].sum
=> 0
```

and the other version

```
/testapp# ruby --version
ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [x86_64-linux]
/testapp# rails --version
Rails 5.1.4
/testapp# rails c
irb(main):001:0> [].sum
=> 0
```